# Oprofile not finding libraries

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, libraries, oprofile, operf

I'm trying to use OProfile on Eclipse (3.8). The Juno version of oprofile didn't work, so I installed the Luna one. This one at least starts up, but can never find the libraries.

Here is the error:

```
ns3-dev-lena-profiling-debug: error while loading shared libraries: libns3-dev-lte-   debug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

profiled app exited with the following status: 127
```

I know that that means I need to add the library path. So I went to Profiling Tools Configurations, and specified the path under environmental variables as:

```
name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
value: {workspace_loc:ns3dev2}/build (appended)
```

I manually checked and the library is located in the build folder. Furthermore, this library path works fine if I debug the same project instead (or run it...).

I've deleted the configuration and remade it, but it's the same error.

I also tried adding the same path to PATH instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but that doesn't make any difference. (Just tried it for the hell of it).

Any thoughts?

Edit, I get the same problem on Eclipse 4.4 (Luna). I found the logs for the errors and the error is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.linuxtools.oprofile.core 4 0 2014-10-27 12:33:07.200
!MESSAGE opreport process error output: warning: /no-vmlinux could not be found.
```

Comment: Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) is very different from Eclipse 3.8, there is no guarantee anything intended for Luna will work on 3.8

Comment: I installed it using the "Install New Software" thing in Eclipse with the option to only show compatible software checked off. I would think that would be enough? Furthermore, path search is different between two Eclipse versions? Also 3.8 == 4.2, so not thaaaat far off.

Comment: I've just installed Eclipse 4.4, and I still get library errors from it.

Comment: Any luck in resolving this? Getting the same error.

Comment: @DonalM The only way I managed to resolve it was to add both libraries using export in terminal, following which I opened Eclipse from the same terminal.